# Passing variable using Button via "command" attribute

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making simple UI in Python using , in which I have 5 similar buttons with different labels on. To make code a little shorter I created buttons in loop like this:

```py
self.btntext = ["-10mm", "-1mm", "Stop", "+1mm", "+10mm"]

self.ctrButtons = []
    for i in self.btntext:
        self.ctrButtons.append(tk.Button(self.buttonFrame, text=i, command= lambda: self.addSubtract(i)))
```

I thought that it would pass current button text to *addSubtract* function but instead it always passes the last element of *btntext*.

Why it works like this? And can I make this work without adding 5 buttons individually?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You almost had it. Your lambda is missing a portion that is required to deal with this very problem:

Change this:

```
lambda: self.addSubtract(i)
```

To this:

```
lambda x=i: self.addSubtract(x)
```

The reason we need to do this is due to how lambdas are executed.
This function does not evaluate the assigned variable until it is called.

To deal with this we force it to evaluate the variable by assigning it to another variable within the lambda as we create them.